# how to disable the page in jquery mobile

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

Hi I am using jquery mobile in my android phonegap application.I am showing the loader in the onload using jquery mobile and when loader is running,i can able to type in the textbox in the html page.But my need is when loader is running i should not able to type in the textbox.How to solve this problem

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $.mobile.loading('show', {
        text: 'Loading',
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'a',
        html:""
    });
});
```

Please Kindly help me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could display a splash page first during loading and then switch to your main page...
and: don't use `$(document).ready()`, see [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)

> **Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.